# User rights needed for Bind-user for LDAP query

Tags: svn, ldap, user-roles

We are implementing Subversion and i'm struggling with the LDAP authentication because i don't want to use my DC's administrator account to execute the LDAP queries, as then I also need to specify its password in plain text in my Apache conf file.

So I created a special Subversion user for this purpose, making a member of Authenticated Users group (as mentioned in numerous posts across the net for being enough to execute a LDAP query).

But when i try to test the LDAP query i want to use in the LDP tool from microsoft, i get the following results:

Binding with administrator: I get all needed users (around 8), complying with the filter settings
Binding with Subversion: I only get a limited set of users (2), not clear why only those.

I tried expanding the groups of Subversion user (like administrators, domain-admins etc), but that didnt work.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I must have done something wrong myself, because after starting from scratch with all settings and test .. it all worked. I suspect there was a typo somewhere that just didn't catch my eye.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a permission issue if Authenticated Users is not sufficient.   It depends on what your query is for, and this does not show in the question.